# Is there something like `inspect_types()` for a numba ' @jitclass`?

Tags: python, class, numba

My numba `@jitclass` fails with a TypingError and an unhelpful error message, once I try to instantiate it: `Can't infer type of variable '$0.1': list(undefined)`. Which variable does that `$0.1` correspond to (ok, probably the first one encountered, but in which function?). With normal functions, `inspect_types()` would be very helpful here. However, It doesn't seem to exist, neither on the jitclass, nor on it's methods. Is there something like that for jitclasses? I'm on numba 0.28.1 (currently the latest stable), but in general, I'm just interested about the most recent version of numba.

Comment: If you are still hung up on the specific error, if you post code, I can probably help debug that specific problem. From poking around, it doesn't look like you can call `inspect_types` on jitclass functions as you noted.

Comment: I found the problem, plain old bisectioning by commenting out worked. I guess I was trying to overstretch what is supported on jitclasses, namely class attributes that are (homogeneous) lists. I could of course use arrays, but the whole point was to speed up an algorithm that relies on fast insertion and deletion of elements.